# Passing NSMutableArray dictionary data to another view using segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, tableview

I have code like this:
In `.m`

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
            {
            [super viewDidLoad];

        arrReceipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        arrReceipesTime1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Half an hour or less",@"About an hour",@"More than an hour", nil];
        NSDictionary *arrReceipeTime1Dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrReceipesTime1 forKey:@"Find Recipes"];
        arrReciepHeart = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"HealthyAndDelicius", nil];
        NSDictionary *arrRecipesHeartDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrReciepHeart forKey:@"Find Recipes"];
        arrRecipeLifestyle = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Recipe for fall",@"Quick and easy",@"Cooking for kids",@"Easy entertaining",@"American classics", nil];
        NSDictionary *arrRecipeLifestyleDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrRecipeLifestyle forKey:@"Find Recipes"];

        [arrReceipes addObject:arrReceipeTime1Dict];
        [arrReceipes addObject:arrRecipesHeartDict];
        [arrReceipes addObject:arrRecipeLifestyleDict];
   }
```

Now, I want to pass values from "arrReceipes"(in which I'm doing "`addObject:dictionaryObject`") to another view controller using segue(or any other way, if you know)

And using "segue" I'm doing it using following:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView1 indexPathForSelectedRow];
       RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

       destViewController.recipeName = [arrReceipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    }

    }
```

I'm getting exception as my "arrReceipes" is `NSMutableArray` assigned with dictionary objects.Instade if taking "`NSMutableArray`", if I'm using "`NSArray`" its working fine. But I want to use "`NSMutableArray`"; because with this I can make group in table view.

Comment: Your explanation at the end is somewhat unclear. Perhaps posting the error message you are getting will make helping you easier.

Comment: What line gives you the exception? Please post the actual error message.

Comment: `recipeName` is NSDictionary or NSArray ????????

Comment: Not an answer but I can't stop myself from plugging the new ObjC literal syntax for NSArray's and NSDictionary's:
    arrReceipes =  @[
        @{@"Find Recipes":@[@"Half an hour or less", @"About an hour", @"More than an hour"]},
        @{@"Find Recipes":@[@"HealthyAndDelicius"]},
        @{@"Find Recipes":@[@"Recipe for fall",@"Quick and easy",@"Cooking for kids",@"Easy entertaining",@"American classics"]}
    ];
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you wanted

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView1 indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        destViewController.recipeName = arrReceipes[indexPath.section][@"Find Recipes"][indexPath.row];
}
```

Which is the same as

```
destViewController.recipeName = [[[arrReceipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"Find Recipes"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```